# How to write unit test case IHttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

I have a method in service layer to  connect to a service and i am using `IHttpClientFactory`. My method is working fine. Now i am trying to write unit test cases for the same.

```
public async Task<MyObject> MyMethodAsync(string arg1, string arg2)
{
    var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("XYZ");

    var Authkey = "abc"; 
    var AuthToken = "def";
       
    var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { Authkey,AuthToken }
        };

    client.AddTokenToHeader(headers); //This method set  the DefaultRequestheader from the dictionary object

    var reqData = new
    {
        prop1 = "X", 
        prop2 = "Y"
    };//req object

    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reqData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    //This is httpClient Post call for posting data 
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("postData", content); 
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode || response.Content == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    MyObject myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);//read the result to an object
    return myObject;
}
```

For the above method i am writing test cases. Here i am trying to set the Post methods out put a status code OK and expecting the
`MyMethodAsync` method to be true as the `PostAsync` is true. Here i am getting an exception

> System.InvalidOperationException : An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.

```
[Test]
public async Task MyMethodAsync_Gets_True()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new StringContent("It worked!")
    };

    //Mock the httpclientfactory
    var _httpMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
    var mockFactory = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>(); 

    //Specify here the http method as post
    _httpMessageHandler.Protected()
      .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync",
       ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(req => req.Method == HttpMethod.Post),
       ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
       .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage
       {
           StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
       });


    var httpClient = new HttpClient(_httpMessageHandler.Object);
    mockFactory.Setup(_ => _.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(httpClient);

    var arg1 = "X";
    var arg2 = "D101";

    var service = new MyService(_mockAppSettings.Object, mockFactory.Object);
    var result = await service.MyMethodAsync(arg1, arg2);
    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

Can someone show what mistake i am doing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the exception says you have to

- either call the `PostAsync` with an absolute url
- or set the `BaseAddress` of the HttpClient

If you choose the second one all you need to do is this:

```cs
var httpClient = new HttpClient(_httpMessageHandler.Object);

httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://nonexisting.domain"); //New code

mockFactory.Setup(_ => _.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(httpClient);
```

---

With this modification the exception will be gone.
But your test will fail because the `response.Content` will be `null` and that's why `MyMethodAsync` will return with `null`.

To fix this let's change the Setup to this:

```
public static async Task MyMethodAsync_Gets_True()
{
    //Arrange
    MyObject resultObject = new MyObject();
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultObject))
    };

    var _httpMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
    _httpMessageHandler.Protected()
        .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync",
          ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(req => req.Method == HttpMethod.Post),
          ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
        .ReturnsAsync(response);
    ...

    //Act
    var result = await service.MyMethodAsync(arg1, arg2);

    //Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
}
```

Comment: I have modified to add the BaseAddress.